# Php view photo by id

Tags: php, mysql

Hi i have an address book I added the possibility of add a photo.
This is the function for view Name,Surname,Email and telephone

```
// Display users  
public function display(){

    $temp_arr = array();

    $res = $this->db->run("SELECT * FROM users ORDER by cognome,nome ");
    $count=$this->db->rowCount();
    while($row = $this->db->fetchArray()) {
         $temp_arr[] =$row;
     }
    return $temp_arr;  

}

<?php 
        $data = $user->display(); 
        $i = 0; 
        foreach( $data as $eachrecord ) {
            $i++;
    ?>
```

my idea was to do so how do i implement it?

```
$sql = "SELECT name FROM upload where id=$id";
$result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);

$image = $row['name'];
$image_src = "uploads/".$image;

<td><img src='<?php echo $image_src;  ?>' ></td>
```

to take id use this function

```
// get id upload
    public function getid(){
        $db = new mysqli("localhost","root","", "rubrica");
        if ($db-> connect_errno) {
        exit();
        }
    $nome = $this->unome;
    $cognome = $this->ucognome;
    $email = $this->uemail;
    $telefono = $this->utel;
    $query = $db->query("SELECT id FROM users WHERE nome='$nome' and cognome='$cognome' and email='$email' and telefono='$telefono'");
    $id = $query->fetch_assoc()['id'];
    $db->close();
    return $id;
    }
```

thank you in advance who will help me!

Comment: Please see about sql injection and the importance of prepared and bound queries

Comment: @Strawberry it will not be published on the web only in local

Comment: Famous last words. What happens is, next time, when you create something similar for the web, you will copy and paste code from here.

Comment: What exactly is your question, what doesn't work?

Comment: @kerbholz I have to add in the function display something for view photo by id the photo is in another table

Comment: You can probably do this in one go in your first query using `JOIN`.

Comment: If you run `echo 'O'Brian';` you get a parse error. Claiming that it doesn't matter because it's a local server doesn't really hold up. SQL Injection is exactly the same, though with the added thrill of being potentially hacked.